# Video Explanation for Web Site

Tags: video

Can you recommend me a program to create video explanations for web sites? Like on dropbox.
Or do you have a list of possible designer web sites who record the video for me?

Thanks,
cas sakal

Answer (score 0):

Not the right place to ask this question! This is a programmer community, with mostly technical content.

Your question is also poorly specified. Try getting advice from a designer in real life, someone that can point you in the right direction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a screen recorder?

- Free but limited features: http://camstudio.org/
- One that's probable better: http://www.zdsoft.com/
- More: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=screen+recorder)